# D3 force layout by node size

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm trying to create a visualization with D3 such that nodes are differently sized by a particular attribute and bigger nodes go to the center and smaller nodes go to the outside. I have sizing and clustering and collision detection working, but I can't figure out how to tell the bigger nodes to go to the center.

I've tried messing with the charge, but couldn't convince that to work. I got linkDistance to move the bigger ones to the center, but (a) getting there was VERY jittery and (b) the smaller ones are way outside rather than tightly packed. The linkDistance is still in the code, just commented out.

It's up at http://pokedex.mrh.is/stats/index.html:

[image]

The relevant code (I assume) is also below. The nodes are sized per their `attr` attribute. Oh, and the nodes are Pokémon.

```
force = d3.layout.force()
// .gravity(0.05)
// .charge(function(d, i) { return d.attr; })
// .linkDistance(function(d) {
//   return 50000/Math.pow(d.source.attr+d.target.attr,1);
// })
.nodes(pokemon)
// .links(links)
.size([$(window).width(), $(window).height()]);
```

Comment: I think you were pretty close - try what you did w `charge()` for `gravity()`.

Answer (score 1):

The following gave me a less jittery version of what you have now.

```
force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.1)
    .charge(function(d, i) { return -d[selectedAttr]})
    .friction(0.9)
    .nodes(pokemon)
    .size([$(window).width(), $(window).height()]);
```

To answer your actual question, each node's coordinates are currently being placed in your graph at random. I quote from the [D3 documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-size):

> When nodes are added to the force layout, if they do not have x and y attributes already set, then these attributes are initialized using a uniform random distribution in the range [0, x] and [0, y], respectively.

From my experience, there's no magic `force` method that gets the nodes you want to the center of the map. The way that I've accomplished your desired result in the past has been by replacing the randomized coordinates of each node with coordinates that place the nodes in a the desired order, expanding from the center of the map.